# Capture photo without camera view in iOS

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation

Is there a way to take a photo using iPhone camera without pushing the camera view on the screen? Normally there would be the camera view with 'take photo' button and some zoom controls. But I want to make a process that takes several images in the background.

Is that possible in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the reference https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2

> To manage the capture from a device such as a camera or microphone,
>   you assemble objects to represent inputs and outputs, and use an
>   instance of AVCaptureSession to coordinate the data flow between them.