# possible to take picture without launching the front camera in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

is possible to take picture without launching the front camera in iphone device

if yes means, give that sample tutorial for refrence.

i want to take picture with front camera . but user will not see the camera screen.
in back end it have to take pictures and save in photo album

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture photo without camera view in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724166/capture-photo-without-camera-view-in-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Pl. see this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html).

In that link, have a look at **Generating a Single Image**.